# What is the Intent action gets raised when the user starts/opens an Application in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

What is the Intent action gets raised when the user starts/opens an Application? Basically I want to execute some code on receiving the above Intent.

Thanks,
poddroid

Comment: "Actually my requirement is to execute some code when the user starts any of the installed applications in his device" -- write your own firmware.

Answer (score 2):

The Intent that triggers the first Activity of an application to run is Intent.ACTION_MAIN, with category Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER.

This is why in the manifest file of any application, the Activity that will be the first screen features the intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

I don't know what code you would need to execute before your Activity's onCreate(Bundle) method, but you can also extend the Application class and override its onCreate() method to execute code before any Activity is created.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually my requirement is to execute some code when the user starts any of the installed applications in his device. My code will be running as background service (..presume..) and catch the Intent and take some appropriate action based on the opened application....... Hope my question is understandable now......(Sorry I was unable to interpret my intention in my last question... )

Comment: Sorry, Intent.ACTION_MAIN is not an Intent that is broadcast, so you can't register to receive this Intent for any application other than your own.